# Why is result of query different when used in Stored proc or when running query from SSMS or DBeaver

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
insert into [dbo].[SEELOG_AGG_DETAIL]
select SEELOG_TMP.NAME_MUT
    , SEELOG_TMP.DESCR_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.FUNCT_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.DEPT_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.[TYPE]
        , SEELOG_TMP.[DATE]
        , count(*) AS NUMBER_RECORDS
        , SEELOG_TMP.ACTION
    from #SEELOG_TMP SEELOG_TMP with (index(#IDX_SEELOG_TMP_2))
    WHERE  (SEELOG_TMP.[TYPE] <> 'O')
        OR (
            SEELOG_TMP.[TYPE] = 'O'
            AND SEELOG_TMP.[MODULE] = 'PS'
            AND SEELOG_TMP.FUNCT_MUT <> ''
            ) 
        OR (
            SEELOG_TMP.[TYPE] = 'O'
            AND SEELOG_TMP.[MODULE] = 'ZP'
            AND SEELOG_TMP.FUNCT = 'LOGIN'
            ) 
    GROUP BY
          SEELOG_TMP.NAME_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.DESCR_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.FUNCT_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.DEPT_MUT
        , SEELOG_TMP.[TYPE]
        , SEELOG_TMP.[DATE]
        , SEELOG_TMP.ACTION
    OPTION (MAXDOP 4);
```

This is the code that creates the temp-table :

```
SELECT ISNULL(USER1.NAAM, '') AS [NAME_USR]
    ,ISNULL(USER1.OMSCHR, '') AS [DESCR_USR]
    ,ISNULL(USER2.NAAM, '') AS [NAME_MUT]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (ISNULL(USER2.OMSCHR, '') = '')
            AND (SEELOG.MODULE = 'ZP')
            THEN '-- Zorgportaal --'
        ELSE ISNULL(USER2.OMSCHR, '')
        END AS [DESCR_MUT]
    ,CAST(CASE 
            WHEN (ISNULL(USERFUNK.OMSCHR, '') = '')
                AND (SEELOG.MODULE = 'ZP')
                THEN ISNULL('-- ' + CASE 
                            WHEN SEELOG.FUNCTIE = 'LOGIN'
                                THEN CASE 
                                        WHEN (
                                                ISNUMERIC(SEELOG.INZAGEINFO) = 0
                                                OR LEN(SEELOG.INZAGEINFO) <> 7
                                                )
                                            AND (LEN(SEELOG.INZAGEINFO) > 0) -- filter op ACTIONURI werkt niet.
                                            THEN SEELOG.FUNCTIE + ' ARTS'
                                        ELSE SEELOG.FUNCTIE
                                        END
                            ELSE SEELOG.FUNCTIE
                            END + ' --', '')
            ELSE ISNULL(USERFUNK.OMSCHR, '')
            END AS NVARCHAR(60)) AS FUNCT_MUT
    ,ISNULL(USERAFD.OMSCHR, '') AS DEPT_MUT
    ,SEELOG.LOGUSERID
    ,LOGSESSI.LOGSESS_ID
    ,LOGSESSI.WINUSER
    ,LOGSESSI.WINSTAT
    ,SEELOG.[TYPE]
    ,SEELOG.[ACTIONURI]
    ,SUBSTRING(SEELOG.ACTIONURI,1, ABS( patindex('%/%', SEELOG.ACTIONURI)-1)) as ACTION
    ,SEELOG.AutoID
INTO #SEELOG_TMP
FROM dbo.SEELOG_SEELOGI SEELOG WITH (READUNCOMMITTED,INDEX (idx_SEELOG_SEELOGI_Primaire_volgorde))
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SEELOG_NDZKKZ NOODKEUZE WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON SEELOG.KEUZE = NOODKEUZE.KeuzeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZISCON_LOGUSER LOGUSER WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON SEELOG.LOGUSERID = LOGUSER.LOGUSER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZISCON_LOGSESSI LOGSESSI WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON LOGSESSI.LOGSESS_ID = LOGUSER.LOGSESS_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZISCON_USER USER1 WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON USER1.NAAM = LOGUSER.GEBRUIKER
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZISCON_USER USER2 WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON USER2.NAAM = LOGUSER.MUTGEBRUIK
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZISCON_USERFUNK USERFUNK WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON USER2.FUNKTIE = USERFUNK.CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZISCON_USERAFD USERAFD WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON USERAFD.CODE = USER2.AFDELING
WHERE 
   SEELOG.AutoId BETWEEN  @AutoId_min_search AND @AutoId_max_search
OPTION (FORCE ORDER, MAXDOP 4);
```

When I want to check what's might be the problem I query the temp-table from the stored-proc, which gives me the wrong result.

When I add a little code like

```
select * info dbo.seelog_tmp from #seelog_tmp
```

which creates a normal database table with the contents of the temp-table, and then I run my query against the normal table, I get a good result. This query includes the column DEPT_MUT.

When in de stored-proc, I exclude the column DEPT_MUT from the query, the stored-proc returns the same result as running the query against the normal table.

When I run the query from DBeaver or from SSMS I get the results that I expect. But when I put the query in a stored-procedure, the result is different. I only get one row when running from stored-procedure, but all the right groups when running from DBeaver or SSMS.

While experimenting with the query (add and remove some columns) I found that the column DEPT_MUT has NULL values. Removing this column from the query and then use the query in stored-procedure, it works.

So, why is the query result different when running in stored-procedure?

Hope someone has an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say without seeing how you create and populate the temp table #SEELOG_TMP

The only way the result would be different is if #SEELOG_TMP was providing different input data, are you sure that you are calculating #SEELOG_TMP the same way in SSMS as well as in the PROC?

Can you show how the proc generates it vs how SSMS creates it?

Comment: Basically I do select * from SEELOG_SEELOG into #SEELOG_TMP. When I change the code into select * from SEELOG_SEELOG into dbo.SEELOG_TMP and then run the query from my question, I get a different result.

Comment: You need to check the code that creates #SEELOG_TMP, if the input is different then the output will be different.

Comment: You aren't just doing an into because the temp table has an index on it, what other transforms are happening? @JaccodeZwart

Comment: So is there a difference in table or column when creating van temp-table or when creating a normal table with the select into statement ? ?

Comment: The difference is in what you put inside the temp table, your question is not complete as it doesn't show how you create the temp table. The only way that the result of your query would be different is if the data *inside* #SEELOG_TMP was different.